# Can python calculate more than 2 input numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm searching but I can't find anything. I can only find with specific amount of numbers, and only one type of mathematic operation at a time. Is there any way to make the printed output to work like normal python without any code, e.x. you type in python:

```
5+3-8*2+6/3
```

the output will be -6. 
Is there any solution, or should I use another programming language, to make such a program?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Something like `eval(input())` ?

Comment: You could use REPL: start python interpreter and type into REPL your expression.

Comment: wow never heard of "eval" ever again.It actually worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eric Duminil For Print A Solution.
a=input("Let me do an operation: ")
print (eval(a))

Comment: Note : This is a potential security risk. The user can enter any python code `import os; os.remove('important_file.txt')`, not just a mathematical expression.